# SearchView: How to remove back button?

Tags: android, searchview, back-button

I've been able to customize my SearchView using this link:  http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/

BUT I can't figure out out to hide the back button once the searchView has focus. Basically, I want the SearchView to be the full width of the Navigation bar.

Comment: updated the answer use search view as field variable ..and if it works please edit my code ...cant edit in mobile properly now..

Comment: the code is structured badly

Comment: Tried, SearchView#setIconifiable(false)?

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos Yes

Comment: you mean the back arrow to the left of the app icon?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. `if(!searchView.isIconified()){ hideBackButton();} else unHideBckButton();`

**Note** write this code in `onResume()` of your activity..